# Converting just one field to int (without comma) in a laravel Json Response

Tags: json, laravel, casting

I am returning an eloquent model :

```
{
    "t": "2020-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "meter_id": "30002",
    "operation_id": "ACC000000",
    "conso_prod": "Conso",
    "d": "14",
    "s": "Pamela",
    "timestep": 600000000000,
    "unit": "kW"
},
```

What I want is `d` to be a float, so, without `""`:

```
{
    "t": "2020-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "meter_id": "30002",
    "operation_id": "ACC000000",
    "conso_prod": "Conso",
    "d": "14",
    "s": "Pamela",
    "timestep": 600000000000,
    "unit": "kW"
},
```

So, I used:

```
    return Response::json($raws, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Which worked great fo `d` field.

But now, I have the field meter_id that has became a integer, and this one, I want it as a string:

Final result I would need:

```
{
    "t": "2020-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "meter_id": "30002",
    "operation_id": "ACC000000",
    "conso_prod": "Conso",
    "d": 14,
    "s": "Pamela",
    "timestep": 600000000000,
    "unit": "kW"
},
```

I also tried to cast fields in the model:

1. Casting `d` to `float`, didn't work
2. Casting `meter_id` to `string`, didn't work neither

If possible, I would like to avoid using `->map()` over result to manually cast the fields, as my collection can be quite big.

What should I do about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest casting the whole object into a custom [`JsonResource`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources). This way you have complete control over what gets outputted, how it gets transformed and how consistent it'll be when you change something within the model:

The Eloquent resource:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            't' => $this->t,
            'meter_id' => (string) $this->meter_id,
            'operation_id' => $this->operation_id,
            'conso_prod' => $this->conso_prod,
            'd' => (int) $this->d,
            's' => $this->s,
            'timestep' => (float) $this->timestep,
            'unit' => $this->unit,
        ];
    }
}
```

To transform a single model use

```
new AResource($raws);
```

and to transform a Eloquent collection use

```
AResource::collection($raws);
```

You can directly return the resource from the controller, it'll act as a response.

Comment: Yes, it can be an option. I think for my use case, I will prefer a map() function, as I only need to write the fields that I need to cast and not all the fields. But it is good to extract transformation from controller, I'll need to think about what is best !

Answer (score 0):

try Laravel cast

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

```php
protected $casts = [
    'meter_id' => 'string',
     'd' => 'integer',
];
```

Comment: that is what I meant when I write: --> Casting meter_id to string, didn't work neither. Already tried it and not working

Comment: remove all the modification by map or loop only keep model casting then it will work remove `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` this as well

Comment: I don't make any map for now, and also remove `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, it is not taking it. That's why I am posting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) php function.

On the other side, i think you should consider using the map collection function to manipulate your array.